# Custom openGL drawing in cocos2dx (3.2)

Tags: c++, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

Im trying to draw a triangle on screen using openGL on cocos2dx. Currently i have subclassed cocos' Node object inside which i do my drawing.

In the latest version of cocos2dx i cannot override the `draw()` function instead im trying to override `draw(Renderer* renderer, const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)` and add Custom commands to the renderer, like so.

```
    const GLfloat vertices[9] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
};



void MyNodeSubclass::draw(Renderer* renderer, const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags){
     CustomCommand *_customCommand = new CustomCommand();
    _customCommand->init(_globalZOrder);
    _customCommand->func = CC_CALLBACK_0(MyNodeSubclass::drawTriangle, this);
    renderer->addCommand(_customCommand);
   }

void MyNodeSubclass::drawTriangle(){
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,0, vertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

And My Load Shader method

```
void MyNodeSubclass::loadOurShaders(){
              GLProgram* myShader = new GLProgram();
              myShader->initWithFilenames("shader.vert", "shader.frag");
              myShader->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_POSITION, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
              myShader->link();
              myShader->updateUniforms();
   }
```

I dont see the triangle on screen. But I'm able to draw cocos2dx primitive objects (polygons , points , lines) by just swapping out whats in my drawTriangle function but not my vertices using openGL.

What am i missing here?

Comment: You have the vertex data in a variable named `vVertices` holding the vertex coordinates, but use a variable `vertices` to specify the vertex attribute. Are they the same?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, its meant to be 'vertices' throughout. Also, on closer inspection it seems like the triangle appears on screen for a very short time (less than a second) and disappears. Any idea what might be happening?